# Shorter way to test range for a certain string

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to create code that will export my Excel invoice sheet to PDF, to a specified file path. The path is based on the whether the invoice lists a certain product, ProductX.

This is what I came up with, but seems cumbersome to loop through every single cell in a range to see if ProductX is there.

Is there an easier way to do this? Appreciate any help!

```
Sub ExportToPDF()
'
Dim file_path As String
Dim search_range As Range
Dim each_cell As Range

' Set search_range as desired search range
Set search_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A53:R56")

For Each each_cell In search_range.Cells
    If InStr(1, each_cell.Value, "ProductX", vbTextCompare) Then
        file_path = Some_path_A
    Else: file_path = Some_path_B
    End If
Next each_cell

'Export the sheet as PDF
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=file_path, Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
        , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Find` for a partial match.

This code assumes that the returned path contains the *filepath* variable you need - you may need to tweak this.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A53:R56").Find("ProductX", , xlFormulas, xlPart)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=rng1.Value, Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
        , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on what **brettdj** has suggested, you can use the proposed code like below...

```
Sub ExportToPDF()
    Dim file_path As String
    Dim search_range As String
    Dim each_cell As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    ' Set search_range as desired search range
    search_range = ActiveSheet.Range("A53:R56")


    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A53:R56").Find("ProductX", , xlFormulas, xlPart)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        file_path = Some_path_A
    Else
        file_path = Some_path_B
    End If

    'Export the sheet as PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=file_path, Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
            , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            True
End Sub
```

Comment: Should be useful for the OP as it wasnt clear how that variable (`Some_path_A`) was being set/used.

Comment: Thanks, works great based on what @brettdj suggested. In this case I no longer need the each_file / search_range variables and removed them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest way is the following:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("A53:R56"), "*ProductX*") = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

which can be further reduced to:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A53:R56"), "*ProductX*") = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

since `ActiveSheet` is the *default* ragnge `worksheet` qualification

Comment: Nice & short and works for my current use case. Correct me if I am wrong - but one potential downside is that you can't adjust the case sensitivity of the search variable, compared to the Find method proposed above?

Comment: `CountIF()` _ignores_ character case:  "Productx" and "productX" are both _counted_ as "ProductX". So that if you want to _ignore_ cases then `CountIF()` will suffice, while if you need to match cases then it's not the way to go. Which one is your actual need?

Comment: Yes for this case I posted character case doesn't matter so `CountIF()` works just fine. If I need differentiate to products by character case in future, will go with other methods. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to find exactly that with just a line of code however it will work only the if you search on 1 column. For your case I think it will work because usually the product name will be in a column. The code is as follows:

```
Dim test As Variant
Product = "ProductX"
' Set search_range as desired search range
search_range = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A53:A56"))
If UBound(Filter(search_range, Product)) > -1 Then
    file_path = Some_path_A
Else
    file_path = Some_path_B
End If
```

You can give it a try and let me know if this works for you. If not I will try to find a way to do it with multiple columns and improve the answer

Comment: Tried this and it works - think you meant `Dim search_range As Variant`. Does seem a little longer compared to the other ones. Was wondering amend it to search over multiple columns, does that involve looping `Transpose` several times?

Comment: Might be the case